# How to use turtle_teleop_key to control specific turtle?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use

```
rosservice call spawn 2 2 0 "NewTurtle"
```

to create another turtle on the screen, how to use turtle_teleop_key command to control it?
It like this command only can control the first turtle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173221/how-to-use-turtle_teleop_key-to-control-specific-turtle?/) by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

write a launch file , type the turtle_teleop_key & two turtle node in two namespace ,just like ns="sim1"& ns="sim2",then you can use one turtle_teleop_key to control two turtle.if you don't know namespace find it in <>

---

Originally posted by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) with karma: 141 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0